# Oracle Application Server 10 download link pls

Tags: oracle, oracle-application-server

I need Oracle Application Server 10.
Please give me the link to download this software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled it and found : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/index.html

Cheers,